# How can I make my Django app scalable for uploading CSV File?

Tags: django, csv, django-models

I want to upload a big csv file (40MB). Now for 1 MB file it is taking almost 1.5 minutes and I think it's not good enough for me. I want to make it so fast. I used bulk create instead of create function but what I notice is that both are taking same amount of time. How can I make it fast? Which procedure is good enough for uploading big csv? Can I give the to django Celery for uploading big csv.

#this is my code

```
def upload_file_view(request):
    start_time = datetime.now()
    form = CsvModelForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        form = CsvModelForm
        obj = Csv.objects.get(activated=False)
        with open(obj.file_name.path, 'r') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)

            for i, row in enumerate(reader):
                if i == 0:
                    pass
                else:
                    print(row)  
                    date = row[0]
                    appl_open = row[1]
                    appl_high = row[2]
                    appl_low = row[3]
                    appl_close = row[4]
                    appl_volume = row[5]
                    appl_adjusted = row[6]
                    dn = row[7]
                    mavg = row[8]
                    up = row[9]
                    direction = row[10]

                    Data.objects.create(
                        date = date,
                        appl_open = appl_open,
                        appl_high = appl_high,
                        appl_low = appl_low,
                        appl_close = appl_close,
                        appl_volume = appl_volume,
                        appl_adjusted = appl_adjusted,
                        dn = dn,
                        mavg = mavg,
                        up = up,
                        direction = direction             
                    )
                   
            obj.activated = True
            obj.save()
            end_time = datetime.now()
            print('Duration: {}'.format(end_time - start_time))

    return render(request, 'core/task.html', {'form' : form})
```

Comment: How many lines are in this CSV? Might just be the reading and iterating over the CSV that is taking the most time, if you remove the saving of the data completely does it affect the time taken significantly?

Comment: So, do you want to make it _scalable_ or do you want to make it _performant_? They're almost related, but actually two separate goals. If you want each request to go faster, that's performance, which can factor into scalability, but scalability might look more like "1000 users can upload CSV files all at once" even if it takes the same 1.5 minutes for all of them. Anyhow. Celery might not be an awful idea in certain implementations for scalability. Maybe even performance. Also remove the `print` line. The I/O to terminal can slow things down a lot... Prefer bulk insert over `create` for each

Comment: @@sytech I tried the bulk_create() but the execution time is almost same. but finally I boost up speed using @transaction.atomic. Can I make it more fast using any other library?